# TensorFlow: Load model and just do a forward pass on an image

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

Is it possible to load my model and just do a single forward operation on an image.

My network is defined as follow:

```
def network(x, weights, biases, name="network"):
    # 1. Hidden layer, ReLU
    layer_1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights["h1"]), biases["b1"])
    layer_1 = tf.nn.relu(layer_1)

    # 2. Hidden layer, ReLU
    layer_2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_1, weights["h2"]), biases["b2"])
    layer_2 = tf.nn.relu(layer_2)

    # Output layer with linear activation
    out_layer = tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_2, weights["out"]), biases["bout"])
    return out_layer

pred = network(x, weights, biases, name="network")
```

I got stuck trying:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

test_image = np.random.randn(900,1)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph("my_model.meta")
    saver.restore(sess, tf.train.latest_checkpoint("/dir/to/model"))
    op_to_restore = graph.get_tensor_by_name("network:0")
```

When I do this, I get the following error:

```
KeyError: "The name 'network:0' refers to a Tensor which does not exist. The operation, 'network', does not exist in the graph."
```

But how do I proceed?

Answer (score 3):

When you define a model, you define a graph. This graph contains operations (nodes) and each node has a unique name.

If you don't explicitly set a name to a node, Tensorflow assigns a name for you.

If you want to execute the chain of operations that are required to evaluate a node, you have to know its name.

In your case, you have to find the name of your `out_layer`. You can access its name using the property `.name`.

```
pred = network(x, weights, biases, name="network")
name = pred.name
print(name)
```

Save this name.

Now, you can restore the graph as you already did, and you can look for the correct name into the graph:

```
graph.get_tensor_by_name(name)
```

where name is the string returned by the `print(name)` executed above.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! When I do that and print the name of the operation I get `Add_3:0` and not `network` as I labeled it. Why is this the case? What is necessary that the name of `pred` is `network`?

Comment: You just have to pass the 'name' parameter to the tf.add node definition, and you're done

Answer (score 2):

You need to know the name of your output node (that gives the predictions) and input node (where data is fed).

Then you can run the output node in your session and use a feed dict of your input node to feed in the input image. Something like:

```
model_result = sess.run(output_node , feed_dict ={input_node : test_image})
```

EDIT:
You haven't given your ops a name so Tensorflow will have given them default names. You get the error because network:0 is not the name of any tensor in your Tensorflow graph.

You can add names to your operations by using '`name=place_your_name_here`' as an argument to your operations you are defining e.g.

```
tf.add(tf.matmul(layer_2, weights["out"]), biases["bout"], name='output')
```

Comment: It still don't see what to do. It is kind of hard since I am just getting started with TensorFlow. I added some more details to my question. Maybe my problem can now be easier understand.

Comment: I tried that doing `etwork(x, weights, biases, name="network")` but I can not access it by `restore=graph.get_tensor_by_name("network")`. Can you please tell me where my error is?

Comment: Your network function does not assign the name you pass in to any operation in the function. You need to assign the name to a tensorflow operation like in my edited answer to be able to access the op by name.